# Contents of url and Contents of path returning nil in AVAudioPlayer(Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avplayer, nsurl

```
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:receivedSongName)
    let urlstring = String(url)
    print("after url  \(urlstring)")
    do{
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: receivedSongName),fileTypeHint: nil)
        player?.delegate = self
        player?.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch{
        print ("Some error")
    }
    if player?.playing == false {
        player?.play()
    }
```

This is my code snippet.I am receiving the 'receivedSongName' from another class on the press of a button by the user.Just for debugging, I am coercing it as string and printing it. The output is something like this in debug window: Haule%20Haule%20-%20www.123musiq.com%20-%20%20%C2%AE%20Riya%20collections%20%C2%AE -- file:/// .So the song path url is created successfully. But when I try to initialise the player, the contentsOfUrl returns nil and it goes to catch block to print: some error. I have imported AVFoundation and also used AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol.Still this problem persists. I have also tried to convert the data into NSData and play the file from there.Here's the code snippet for that.

```
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:receivedSongName)
    let data : NSData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(String(url))!
   let urlstring = String(url)
    print("after url  \(urlstring)")
    do{
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data)
    player?.delegate = self
    player?.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch{
        print ("Some error")
    }
```

Here, data cannot be initialised because contentsAtPath returns nil and hence a nil is found while unwrapping an optional.So,stuck in a fix. Any help would be extremely appreciated.